# Window 8 content overflow

Tags: windows-8, window, vga

I don't know why but this is how my windows displays after i installed a  VGA.

It overflows at the top and leave a blank black line at the bottom.

I removed the VGA but its still like that

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your monitor settings else you could undo that VGA installation